# In bash, replace each character of a string with a fixed character ("blank out" a string)

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion, shellcheck

MWE:

```
caption()
{
    echo "$@"
    echo "$@" | sed 's/./-/g'  # -> SC2001
}

caption "$@"
```

I'd like to use parameter expansion in order to get rid of the shellcheck error. The best idea I had was to use `echo "${@//?/-}"`, but this does not replace spaces.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$*` to save it in a local variable:

```sh
caption() {
   local s="$*"
   printf '%s\n' "$s" "${s//?/-}"
}
```

**Test:**

```sh
caption 'SC 2001' foo bar

SC 2001 foo bar
---------------
```